# Ionic v4 - check if modal is opened

Tags: angular, ionic4

Basically I have welcome page with 2 buttons; login and register. When the user clicks “register” button a modal opens up showing the registration form. I implemented a logic to login the user upon registration and theres also a logic that takes the user to the home page when he/she is authenticated.

What this means is that when the user submit the registration form and log in, the modal has to be dismissed, but **only** after the home page is being displayed. Otherwise if I close the modal before that then the user is going to see the welcome screen again, and I would like to avoid that behavior. I could easily dismiss the modal upon registration but as I said, I don't want the user to see the welcome screen again.

This is how I open the modal in **welcome.ts**

```
async showModal() {
    const modal = await this.modalController.create({
      component: RegisterPage
    });
    return modal.present();
  }
```

In **register.ts**, I need a way to know if the modal is still opened so I can use the following logic:

```
constructor(
    private modalController: ModalController,
    private router: Router
  ) {
    this.router.events.subscribe(() => {
      if (router.url.toString() === "/tabs/home" && isModalOpened) this.modalController.dismiss();
    });
  }
```

If I only add this to my if statement `router.url.toString() === "/tabs/home"` it works, but if the user from the welcome screen opens the modal (by pressing the register button) and closes it w/o submitting the register form, go back to the welcome screen, press the login button and log in, then I will get an error:

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): overlay does not exist

And of course this happens because I am dismissing the modal when I am the the home page, w/o checking if the modal is opened.

Any help is greatly appreciated, I’ve been stuck with this for a while now…

Answer (score 10):

You can call the `this.modalCtrl.getTop();` function. If it is undefined, it means the component was not called through a Modal Controller instance. You can refactor your code like:

```
constructor(
    private modalController: ModalController,
    private router: Router
  ) {
    this.router.events.subscribe(async () => {
      const isModalOpened = await this.modalController.getTop();
      if (router.url.toString() === "/tabs/home" && isModalOpened) this.modalController.dismiss();
    });
  }
```

Comment: in that case, `async` will not return you the exact current route

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this way;

```
async showModal() {
    this.modal = await this.modalController.create({
      component: RegisterPage
    });
    return this.modal.present();
}
```

and check any where

```
if (this.modal) {
  this.modalController.dismiss();
}
```

you should clear its value after dismiss() if your case needs that.